# POSTing object from AngularJS to .net WebAPI is always null

Tags: angularjs, http, post, asp.net-web-api, service

I tried everything yet still when debugging the value at the web api post action is always null.
i tried changing the headers, i added [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)] above the posted model class, i tried a simple Dto. nothing works...
this is the controller function that passes the user data:

```
$scope.Add = function () {
        var user = {
            ID: $scope.ID,
            FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
            LastName: $scope.LastName,
            Age: $scope.Age,
            Address: $scope.Address
        };
        $scope.usersRepo.push(user);
        myService.addUser(user);
```

the service function is:

```
var addUser = function (user) {
        return $http.post(
            usersApi + '/addNewUser',
            JSON.stringify(user)),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };
    };
```

and the web api action is:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("addUser")]
    public void Post([FromBody]UserModel value)
    {
        UsersDB.Add(value);
    }
```

my model is this:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
public class UserModel
{
    public UserModel()
    {

    }
    public UserModel(string firstName, string lastName, int age, string address)
    {
        this.Address = address;
        this.Age = age;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    public void ConvertDto(UserDto userDto)
    {
        ID = userDto.ID;
        FirstName = userDto.FirstName;
        LastName = userDto.LastName;
        Age = userDto.Age;
        Address = userDto.Address;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Generally there is no need to stringify POST data as the AngularJS $http service does that automatically. Also need to add the `application/json` header as that is the default.

Comment: That was my starting point.

Comment: I made the comment so that others won't copy needless code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http post method like this. data should be your object to be passed without json stringify. I advised you to create a service for http methods.

```
 var obj = {
        url: your url,
        async: true,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        }
    };
    if (typeof data != 'undefined' && typeof data != null) {
        obj.data = data;
    }
    $http(obj).then(function() {}, function() {});
```

Service :
// http methods

```
app.service('MethodProvider', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.get = function (url, data) {
        var obj = {
            url: url,
            async: true,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        if (typeof data != 'undefined' && data != null) {
            obj.params = data;
        }
        return $http(obj);
    };
    self.post = function (url, data) {
        var obj = {
            url: url,
            async: true,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            }
        };
        if (typeof data != 'undefined' && typeof data != null) {
            obj.data = data;
        }
        return $http(obj);
    };
     self.put = function (url, data) {
        var obj = {
            url: url,
            async: true,
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        if (typeof data != 'undefined' && data != null) {
            obj.data = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
        return $http(obj);
    };
    self.delete = function (url) {
        var obj = {
            url: url,
            async: true,
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        if (typeof data != 'undefined' && data != null) {
            obj.data = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
        return $http(obj);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Are you assigning user to obj.data ?

Comment: thank you ! it works only when i write obj.data = user. not working with obj.user=user. same with the  previous solution: if i send a variable name data it works. do you know why is that?

Comment: The expression `typeof data != 'undefined' || typeof data != null` always `true`. What is your intention with that expression?